# What principle makes the system stock icon automatically adapt to the gnome shell theme?

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-shell, gjs

I test a gnome shell extension.

When I set a icon using `icon_name`, I think the gnome shell search and find the icon in system icon path, just like "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/status/alarm-symbolic.svg". And the icon display in panel show `white` but the file is really `black` one, it fit my dark theme.

```
stock_icon.icon_name = 'alarm-symbolic';
```

It appear just like left one in screenshot.

---

When I copy the svg file into extension root directory, and load it by name, it appear just like the right one in screenshot, it's `dark`.

```
stock_icon.gicon = Gio.icon_new_for_string("xxxxx/yyyy.svg");
```

[image: screenshot]

So why the stock one can auto adapt the theme?

Comment: Have you tried just naming it `yyyy-symbolic.svg`?

Comment: thanks, it works, so any document tell the reason?

Comment: I don't recall where this is documented, it may be a part of the GTK documentation.

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/themed-icons.html